# Replace user names by numbers and count number of orders

Tags: r

Data:

```
DB <- structure(list(orderItemID = 1:10, CustomerName = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("Alex", "Bert", 
"Corel", "Dennis", "Edgar", "Fred"), class = "factor"), OrderID = structure(c(5L, 
6L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("14", "17", "33", 
"56", "58", "62", "89", "9"), class = "factor"), ArticleDescription = structure(c(10L, 
5L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 9L, 6L), .Label = c("Adidas Jacket", 
"Adidas Shoes", "Aesics Shoes", "Boss Jeans", "Lee T-Shirt", 
"Nike Airs", "Nike Shoes", "Puma Backpack", "Puma Socks", "Wrangler Jeans"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("orderItemID", "CustomerName", 
"OrderID", "ArticleDescription"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Expected Outcome:

```
output <- structure(list(orderItemID = 1:10, Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6"), class = "factor"), NumberOfOrders = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
    ArticleDescription = structure(c(10L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 
    4L, 2L, 9L, 6L), .Label = c("Adidas Jacket", "Adidas Shoes", 
    "Aesics Shoes", "Boss Jeans", "Lee T-Shirt", "Nike Airs", 
    "Nike Shoes", "Puma Backpack", "Puma Socks", "Wrangler Jeans"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("orderItemID", "Name", 
"NumberOfOrders", "ArticleDescription"), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Good morning!

This time I need to replace the `CustomerName` by numbers beginning with 1 - the same name should have the same number - and the next name should have the next higher number. Additionally the `OrderID` should be replayed by the number of orders the specific customer ordered - in this case when the order ID of diffent articles is equal, it´s one order (eg. Alex did 2 orders (in the first one he ordered "Wrangler Jeans" and in the second one he orderes "Lee T-Shirt"); Dennis did 2 orders too (in the first one he ordered "Aesics Shoes" and in the second one he ordered "Boss Jeans" and "Adidas Shoes")Finally I want to keep the `ArticleDescription` untouched

Comment: Please fix your samples. They throw errors

Comment: Did my best-hope it works now :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

DB %>% mutate(Name = dense_rank(CustomerName), 
          No.of.Orders=(ifelse(is.na(OrderID !=lag(OrderID)), TRUE, (OrderID !=lag(OrderID)))*1 )) %>% 
  group_by(CustomerName) %>% 
mutate(No.of.Orders = cumsum(No.of.Orders))
```

Comment: It´s working - but the last line (out of the other solution) not - just want to delete CustomerName and OrderID: do you have a solution?

Comment: Just select the columns you want. Write the following after %>% select(orderid, Name, No.of.orders)

Comment: ok-works nearly perfect but still shows me the Customer names first...why? 2.:how can I save it?

Answer (score 1):

One way using `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)
DB %>% 
  mutate(Name = as.integer(as.factor(CustomerName))) %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  mutate(No.of.Orders = data.table::rleid(OrderID)) %>% 
  select(-c(CustomerName, OrderID))

#Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
#Groups: Name [6]

#   orderItemID ArticleDescription  Name No.of.Orders
#         (int)             (fctr) (int)        (int)
#1            1     Wrangler Jeans     1            1
#2            2        Lee T-Shirt     1            2
#3            3      Adidas Jacket     2            1
#4            4         Nike Shoes     3            1
#5            5      Puma Backpack     3            1
#6            6       Aesics Shoes     4            1
#7            7         Boss Jeans     4            2
#8            8       Adidas Shoes     4            2
#9            9         Puma Socks     5            1
#10          10          Nike Airs     6            1
```

Comment: `Name = as.integer(as.factor(CustomerName))` might be simpler than requiring a data.table call.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Name pretty easily as

```
number_of_orders <- table(DB$CustomerName)
name <- rep(1:length(unique(DB$CustomerName)),
        number_of_orders)
```

but I think Alex's suggestion is better.